WebPack imports externals with CommonJS instead of ES6
Application description
Express application using webpack to get bundled
Problem
Can't bundle app because dependencies (i.e. webpack's externals) are imported using CommonJS instead of ES modules.
Expected behavior
Externals should be imported using something like __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_createRequire
Example
import path from 'node:path';
import express from 'express';
import {router} from 'express-file-routing';

const __dirname = import.meta.dirname;

const app = express();

app.use(
  '/api',
  await router({directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'routes')}),
);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});

This code produces the following when being bundled
// clip
/***/ "express-file-routing":
/*!***************************************!*\
  !*** external "express-file-routing" ***!
  \***************************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = require("express-file-routing");

/***/ }),

/***/ "node:path":
/*!****************************!*\
  !*** external "node:path" ***!
  \****************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_createRequire(import.meta.url)("node:path");

/***/ })

// clip

Error
file:///path/to/my/application/backend/dist/bundle.js:28
module.exports = require("express");
^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/path/to/my/application/backend/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at Object.express (file:///path/to/my/application/backend/dist/bundle.js:28:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///path/to/my/application/backend/dist/bundle.js:72:40)
    at eval (webpack://gestore-consensi-backend/./index.ts?:5:65)
    at __webpack_require__.a (file:///path/to/my/application/backend/dist/bundle.js:129:12)
    at eval (webpack://gestore-consensi-backend/./index.ts?:1:21)
    at ./index.ts (file:///path/to/my/application/backend/dist/bundle.js:18:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///path/to/my/application/backend/dist/bundle.js:72:40)
    at file:///path/to/my/application/backend/dist/bundle.js:193:36
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:262:25)
    at async onImport.tracePromise.__proto__ (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:482:26)

Node.js v22.8.0

Configuration files
webpack.config.js
import path from 'node:path';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

const __dirname = import.meta.dirname;

export default {
  entry: './index.ts',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  externalsType: 'module',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.controller.ts', '.service.ts'],
    alias: {
      '@controllers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/controllers/'),
      '@services': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/services/'),
      '@middlewares': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/middlewares/'),
    },
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    module: true,
    libraryTarget: 'module',
    chunkFormat: 'module',
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
};


package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=22.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.12.0",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.8.1",
    "eslint": "^9.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^17.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^56.0.0",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "prettier-config-xo": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "tsx": "^4.19.1",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.8.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "express-file-routing": "^3.0.3"
  }
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",     
    "module": "ES2022",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@controllers/*": ["controllers/*.controller"],
      "@services/*": ["services/*.service"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["middlewares/*.middleware"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["interfaces/*.interface"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}

